# Unable to present AlertController from a UIView in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uialertcontroller

I am trying to display an AlertController in Swift, but not from a UIViewController, but from a UIView that is called from its parent UIViewController.  When I try to call the controller, I am getting the following error:

```
Warning: Attempt to present <UIAlertController: 0x7fa5544a3140> on
<UINavigationController: 0x7fa553830400> whose view is not in the window
hierarchy!
```

The code that I have which is trying to call the alertController is this:

```
let logInButton = TWTRLogInButton { (session, error) in
            if let unwrappedSession = session {
                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Logged In",
                    message: "User \(unwrappedSession.userName) has logged in",
                    preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert
                )
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
                //self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            } else {
                NSLog("Login error: %@", error!.localizedDescription);
            }
        }
```

The commented line in the above block of code is what the original block of code came with, and the line below the comment is the code I tried to replace it with.  Can anyone see what it is I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Is the root view controller already presenting a view controller?  If so, you may need to use:

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController?.presentedViewController?.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Having said that, it might be easier (and more consistent/appropriate) to use a delegate pattern and let the view tell whatever view controller is managing it to present the alert view controller.

Comment: Thanks very much for your solution.  While it does work, I am curious about the delegate solution you mentioned.  Can you elaborate on this a little further?

Comment: You can create a delegate `protocol` for your view and have your view controller adopt it.  The protocol would specify a method (such as, `loginViewDidLoginSuccessfully(loginView: SomeLoginViewClass, withUsername username: String)`.  This is the same approach that a `UITableView` or `UICollectionView` uses communicates with a `UIViewController` (many other components in the SDK use this same pattern).  Imagine if you had to hard code the logic for what happens when you select a cell - it would make `UITableView` much less re-usable.

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 5

```
let window = UIApplication.shared.windows.filter {$0.isKeyWindow}.first

window?.rootViewController?.presentedViewController?.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

***for swift 5 :***

```
UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.presentedViewController?.present(alertName, animated: true, completion: nil)
```